# React-native App Crash only on ios TestFlight with RCTFata + 676 exception

Tags: ios, react-native

My React-Native app crashes on TextFlight with RCTFata + 676 exception. It works fine on xcode simulator but it crashes right after start and crash report is like below.

[image: Eroor Photo]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... Did you manage to find the cause?